# How to determine why solr stops running?

Tags: solr

I am using Apache Solr as my search server.  About 1-2 times per week, it stops running.  If I check the apache uptime, I see this is not due to an Apache restart or server reboot.

I have looked in the Solr logs and Apache logs, but I don't see any obvious clues.

How can I determine why Solr stops?

My versions:
Red Hat Linux 7.8, Solr 7.7.2

My /etc/default/solr.in.sh looks like...

```
SOLR_PORT="8983"

SOLR_HEAP=8g
# Use G1 GC  -- wunder 2017-01-23
# Settings from https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ShawnHeisey
GC_TUNE=" \
-XX:+UseG1GC \
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled \
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m \
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
-XX:+UseLargePages \
-XX:+AggressiveOpts \
"
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's getting OOM-killed by your OS. Under Linux you can check this in `/var/log/syslog` - it'll display a message about what process is getting killed

Comment: When I grep for oom-kill in the log files, there is nothing there.  Is there some other string I should grep for?  I'm not sure what am oom-killer log entry would look like.  Is there some way I can move past guessing?  Many thanks.

Comment: grep for `killed process`. Usually these will stick out and be easily seen in Solr nodes that doesn't do much more, at least when you start looking around the time when the node disappeared.